# Convert steps to publish function app to artifact in Azure Pipeline to GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following three steps to publish a function app to artifact in Azure Pipeline:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish function app'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output updater_publish_output'
    projects: 'Service/XYZ/Hosts.FA/*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'archive function app files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/updater_publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Hosts.FA.zip"
 
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish function app files'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Hosts.FA.zip'
    ArtifactName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Here is the project structure:

[image]

I have updated the first step to:

```
- name: dotnet publish function app
      run: dotnet publish Service/XYZ/Hosts.FA/Hosts.FA.csproj --configuration Release --output updater_publish_output
```

How do I convert the tasks  ArchiveFiles@2 & PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Upload-Artifact` task from here: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact. It will replace both `ArchiveFiles@2` (zipping) and `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` (uploading).

```
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: ${{github.run_number}}
    path: |
      updater_publish_output
```

As per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context `github.run_number` is

> A unique number for each run of a particular workflow in a repository. This number begins at 1 for the workflow's first run, and increments with each new run. This number does not change if you re-run the workflow run.

You could also use `github.run_id`:

> A unique number for each run within a repository. This number does not change if you re-run the workflow run.

Comment: Is there a way to archive files in GitHub action. Because I need to upload a .zip format in Artifact.

Comment: You automatically get a zip file when downloading an artifact

Comment: Could you please let me know if it is possible to zip inside folders (archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Hosts.FA.zip")